# Inline JS (OnMouseOver) - Repeat Something Until MouseOut Occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to run a given function every 10ms, considering that I am limited to running only inline code (no external js files or  tags)?

I can only use:

```
<div onmouseover="functions here" onmouseout="functions here">
```

To be more specific I want to move another element to the left with 50px every 10ms using marginLeft, but I can not run externail functions or js libraries as mentioned above.

I was thinking of maybe incorporating it all in the onmouseover with setInterval(function, 10), but I don't see a way of stopping this when the mouseout occurs.

I know I can use jQuery event handlers like .on, but these are not an option here since they will have to be externally loaded (not inline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a global variable:

```
<div onmouseover="if (!window.intervalId)
                  window.intervalId=setInterval(function() {/*your code*/}, 10);"
          onmouseout="clearInterval(window.intervalId); window.intervalId=null;">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the onmouseout does not stop the action in this case. If I try to run the code in the Chrome Javascript console it returns null as well.